# Is the difference between md5, sha1 and sha256 sums the less important the larger the file?

Tags: hashsum

I am compressing a number of files with size in the order of 5GB before sharing them.

On the one hand, I would like to provide a hash sum for the recipient to check the files' integrity. On the other hand, generating a sha256sum of a large file takes some time if you don't have a powerful machine and I did not want to overburden the recipients' computer.

I then wondered whether a faster sha1 sum would provide the same integrity guarantees as a slower sha256sum, simply because the files are big enough.

Take note that security is not a concern here: mainly, it is about knowing that the data have not been accidentally corrupted during upload, storage and download.

---

Question stimulated by this other answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260519/132913

Comment: fwiw, https://shattered.it/ with two different valid PDF with the same size, the same sha1 hash but different content: [PDF1](https://shattered.it/static/shattered-1.pdf) [PDF2](https://shattered.it/static/shattered-2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

> Take note that security is not a concern here: mainly, it is about knowing that the data have not been accidentally corrupted during upload, storage and download.

If that's not a concern there's no need to use more advanced and CPU intensive hashing algos. The possibility of a random transmission bit (or several bits) failure generating the same md5 hash is pretty much zero. E.g. even CRC32 might be enough in this case.

Personally when I need to send someone data and I have to be sure it's going to be sent without errors, I compress using RAR and add a recovery (1%) record. There are no native Unix utilities for that but you can combine compressing with sending `par2` recovery data but we're talking about multiple files.

Comment: To calculate the crc you can use the `cksum` or `crc32` commands. they are calculating both crc32 but have a different output format. This is even faster than any hashing algortihm but also very easy to crack as a MITM. (ethernet is using crc32 to test if the transmission of a package was correct)

Comment: What is a recovery record? (Note as addition that I will not put the files in an archive, because they are many and bulky; I will put them in a repository for future users to pick the one of their choice.)

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=what+is+rar+recovery+record

Comment: Also https://superuser.com/questions/1362786/how-does-winrar-recovery-record-work